# Decrypt encrypted RSA Private Key on the Browser side

Tags: cryptography, pki, webcrypto-api, webcrypto

I have an encrypted private RSA key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,B92E0E3A7B... // <--- IV here.
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I need to decrypt it via a passphrase, basically I need the equivalent of

```
openssl rsa -in <encrypted_private.key>  -out <decrypted_private.key>
```

on the browser side with an Angular based client, using webcrypto and pkijs.

Comment: You need to redesign your system.  Private key must not be handled in browser for security reasons..!!

Comment: Since only the user on the client end, can decrypt his private key, it shouldn't be a problem. All blockchains (Dapps) work that way. The Private Key is secured via a passphrase, which is only known to the user. I don't see here any security issues. Could u be more specific why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So for anyone who will in the future maybe face the same issue like I did:

**PKI.js** is providing an examples folder in their repo:
[OpenSSLPrivateKeyEncryption](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/blob/master/examples/OpenSSLPrivateKeyEncryption/es6.js)

In there you will find a method called decrypt.
With the code I were able to decrypt my AES-CBC Private key.

Comment: The link is broken. Answers on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. This answer should probably be a comment on the question as this post does not include a solution.